# Windows 8 winword.exe stopped interacting with windows

Tags: windows-8, printing, microsoft-word-2013

Aggs 2 days ago, seeminghly withot provocation on my part, MS Word 2013 stopped working. Can't view/preview/print anything related to word docs.

**My specs** :

```
OS Microsoft 8 Pro
Time Zone   Eastern Daylight Time
Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 8.00 GB
Total Physical Memory   7.75 GB
Available Physical Memory   4.99 GB
Total Virtual Memory    15.5 GB
Available Virtual Memory    12.6 GB
Page File Space 7.75 GB
Page File   C:\pagefile.sys
```

Here's the event log details for the first event related to the appplication hanging, as well as a few of the most recent errors/events:

**The oldest and initial event log:**

```
Log Name: Application
Source: Application Hang
Date: 24/10/2015 11:24:10 PM
Event ID: 1002
Task Category: (101)
Level: Error
Keywords: Classic
User: N/A
Description: The program WINWORD.EXE version 12.0.6545.5000 stopped interacting with Windows and was closed. 
Process ID: b18
Start Time: 01cc219d5778e762
Termination Time: 25
Application Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\WINWORD.EXE
Report Id: 

Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.micro.../events/event">
<System>
<Provider Name="Application Hang" />
<EventID Qualifiers="0">1002</EventID>
<Level>2</Level>
<Task>101</Task>
<Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-10-24T03:24:10.000000000Z" />
<EventRecordID>17911</EventRecordID>
<Channel>Application</Channel>
<Computer>Scott-PC</Computer>
<Security />
</System>
<EventData>
<Data>WINWORD.EXE</Data>
<Data>12.0.6545.5000</Data>
<Data>b18</Data>
<Data>01cc219d5778e762</Data>
<Data>25</Data>
<Data>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office13\WINWORD.EXE</Data>
<Data>
</Data>
<Binary>55006E006B006E006F0077006E0000000000</Binary>
</EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: Did you try [Repair an Office application](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Repair-an-Office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b)?

Comment: No, I haven't. I have run MSOffice Diagnostics, with no problems found. If you think that reinstalling Word will help, I'll try it, however, consider this---> the problem seemed to begin and persist with word, but I other functions with other programs (Adobe Reader and other PDF printers/editors) have experienced printing hangs (the "______ program is not responding) when I print from them, so I wonder if the problem is solely isolated to Word.

Comment: It's a repair not a reinstall. If the repair doesn't work then the next step would be a reinstall of word (or office).

Comment: yeah i'm now repairing. not finished. What do you think it is not related windows drivers?

Comment: You could also try reinstalling your printer driver(s). And maybe `sfc /scannow` [How to Run "SFC /SCANNOW" Command at Boot or in Windows 8 and 8.1](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/3047-sfc-scannow-command-run-windows-8-a.html). `sfc` is used to repair corrupted or modified system files.

Comment: i'm just try it now.

Comment: Thanks Mr. DavidPostill. sfc /scannow return successfully answer. But not solved my problem.

Comment: I have no more ideas at the moment :/

Comment: Now, thanks bro, l solved my problem by uninstalling and installing win office 2010 version. It's working perfectly.